# Migrate Android Studio project to Livecode?

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, livecode

Is there any way to migrate an existing Android Studio project into LiveCode?

Haven't seen anything on LiveCode's resources or on Google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing within LiveCode that does this and no 3rd Party tool that could that I've heard of. I think rewriting it is your only option...